# How to monitor incoming messages rate on a particular partition of a kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

How can I know rate at which messages are coming on a particular partition of a kafka topic? Is there any CLI command to achieve this?

Comment: Dont use a CLI if you want to watch a rate. Have you looked over the JMX metrics for the broker?